# Datatable order by

Tags: laravel, datatable

i would like to ask some solution in my datatable, my datatable is ordered by `created_at`,
for example like this:
[image: Datatable]

The data is sucessfully ordered by date, but there was some row or data which has `isdisabled` status and been marked by color in their row and they are being put in top of the row, while the data that are not disabled and has recent `created_at` is being putting after the disabled rows, is there a way to make the data ordered correctly by their date? thank you!.

Here is my controller :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $data = MediaOrder::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
        return DataTables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action',function($row){
                    $btn = '<a style="margin:5px" href="javascript:void(0)" id="viewMediaOrder" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="View" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm button1 viewMediaOrder" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"><i class="fa fa-eye mr-1"></i>View</a>';


                    if(!$row->isdisabled){
                        $btn = $btn.'<a style="margin:5px" href="javascript:void(0)" id="editMediaOrder" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-warning btn-sm button1 editMediaOrder" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil mr-1"></i>Edit</a>

                        <a style="margin:5px" href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" id="disableMediaOrder"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm button1 disableMediaOrder" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"><i class="fa fa-power-off mr-1"></i>Disable</a>';

                    }

                        return $btn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
    } else {

        \Meta::set('title', 'Media Order');
        $groups = Group::all();
        $media_order = DB::table('media_order')->get();
        $moo = MediaOrder::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
        $users = User::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
        return view('media-order.index')->with(compact('users','moo','groups'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do disabled rows have `created_at`?

Comment: no the disabled rows are just tinyint and contain only 0 and 1, which 1 is `isdisabled`